# Fluctuations of vielbein and its relation to metric

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

Suppose

$$
e_{\mu}^{a} \rightarrow e_{\mu}^{a} + \frac{1}{2} H^{a b} e_{b \mu}
$$

Assuming $H_{ab} = H_{ba}$, with the notation of

\begin{align}
H_{\mu \nu} = H_{ab} e_{\mu}^{a} e_{\nu}^{b}
\end{align}

and the relation $g_{\mu \nu}= e_{\mu}^{a} e_{\nu a}$,

one have
$
g_{\mu \nu} \rightarrow g_{\mu \nu} + H_{\mu \nu} + \frac{1}{4} H^{\lambda}_{\mu} H_{\lambda \nu} := g_{\mu \nu} + h_{\mu \nu}.
$

I want to do the backwards, i.e., given $g_{\mu \nu} \rightarrow  g_{\mu \nu} + h_{\mu \nu}$, want to express $H_{\mu}^{a}$ in terms of $h$.

---

It seems stackexchange has some problem for typing tex for lower indices.

Basically I am trying to derive equation 14 in arXiv 1901.06400.

[image]

It is quite easy to obtain equation 13 from itself but I have trouble obtaining equation 14.

How one can convert $H$ into $h$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is essentially solving perturbatively equation (13). The way I usually proceed is as follows. I'd write equation (13) as

$$ H_{\mu \nu} = h_{\mu \nu} - \frac{1}{4}H_{\lambda \mu}H^{\lambda}_{\nu}$$

and then iteratively plug in the expression for $H_{\mu \nu}$ to the RHS of this equation. Therefore I would have

$$ H_{\mu \nu} = h_{\mu \nu} - \frac{1}{4}(h_{\lambda \mu} - \frac{1}{4}H_{\rho \lambda} H^{\rho}_{ \mu})(h^{\lambda}_{ \nu} - \frac{1}{4}H_{\tau}^{\lambda} H^{\tau}_{ \nu})$$

Now this is an exact equation. You can now expand to 3rd order in $H$ and then plug in $H = h$ for the third order terms. That expansion is now true up to $\mathcal{O}(H^4)$.